# SSRS not inclusive for dates; While Management Studio is?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssms, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

Why is it that when I run the query in Management Studio with the following where clause, it returns the data correctly when the cash_date equals the parameter, FromDate.

```
 FILMTRAN.cash_date >= (@FromDate) AND
```

However, when I copy the same query to SSRS it no longer includes the data where the @FromDate equals the cash_date.  The user enters in the parameter in SSRS.  I even did a test where I displayed the full date including the time and did an if statement that returned "yay" if they matched or "no" if they did not.  Even according to SSRS, they match, but than why is my data not being returned when it occured on the same day?!  I am dumbfounded this is not working, when it clearly works in management studio.

I have even tried adding a dateadd function into my sql statement, which again responds correctly in management studio but not ssrs.

Edit: I tested the >= using a much simpler 3 line query and it worked as intended but it is still not working for my query, which works in management studio but not SSRS.  So now I am thinking there is some very specific bug associated with something in my longer query which I have attached. To test my code in management studio I declare the variables as seen below.  However, I delete this code when I import my query into SSRS and instead create the parameters within SSRS(just as I have always done, with no problems).

```
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATETIME
SET @FromDate = '1-Oct-2013'
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATETIME
SET @ToDate = '8-Apr-2015'
DECLARE @Loan AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @Loan = 'TAX_B'
```

[image]

```
SELECT distinct LOANMAST.loan, 
CARDINDX.DESCRIPTION AS BorrowerName, 
CARDINDX.contact_name,
CARDINDX.in_care_of,
--loan_ipt.interest,
CARDINDX.mail_address1, 
CARDINDX.mail_address2,
CARDINDX.mail_city, 
CARDINDX.mail_state,
CARDINDX.mail_country,
LOANMAST.closed_date,
PROPERTY.STATE,
CARDINDX.MAIL_ZIP_CODE, 
PROPERTY.address1, 
PROPERTY.address2,
PROPERTY.city, 
PROPERTY.ZIPCODE, 
PROPERTY.country,
FILMTRAN.cash_date, 
CASE FILMTRAN.TRAN_SUBTYPE WHEN 'REGINST' THEN 'Regular Collections'
WHEN 'PAC' THEN 'PAC'
WHEN 'CORREST' THEN 'Group Collection'
WHEN 'ESCROWTAX' THEN 'Tax Disbursement'
WHEN 'SUNDRY' THEN 'Tax Refund'
WHEN 'FULL PAY' THEN 'Payoff'
END AS TRANSUBTYPE,
FILMTRAN.TAX_ESCROW,
FILMTRAN.TRANSACTION079,
JK.taxescrowbalance,
CASE FILMTRAN.TRANSACTION079 WHEN 'COLLECTION' THEN FILMTRAN.TAX_ESCROW
WHEN 'DISBURSEMENT' THEN 0 
END AS TAXESCROWCOLL,
CASE FILMTRAN.TRANSACTION079 WHEN 'DISBURSEMENT' THEN FILMTRAN.TAX_ESCROW *-1
WHEN 'COLLECTION' THEN 0 
END AS TAXESCROWDIS

FROM LOANMAST LEFT OUTER JOIN BORROWER ON LOANMAST.loan=BORROWER.loan
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LOANCOLL ON LOANMAST.loan=LOANCOLL.loan
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PROPERTY ON LOANCOLL.code=PROPERTY.prop_code
 LEFT OUTER JOIN BALHIST ON BALHIST.loan=LOANMAST.loan
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CARDINDX ON BORROWER.SHORT_NAME=CARDINDX.SHORT_NAME
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LOAN_IPT ON LOAN_IPT.short_name=CARDINDX.short_name
 LEFT OUTER JOIN FILMTRAN ON FILMTRAN.loan=LOANMAST.loan 
JOIN (
 SELECT distinct FILMTRAN.loan, FILMTRAN.cash_date,  FILMTRAN.transaction079 ,FILMTRAN.tax_escrow,
sum(FT.taxescrowcoll)+sum(FT.taxescrowdis)+isnull(BH.esc_tax_bal_p, 0) AS "TaxEscrowBalance" 
from 
FILMTRAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT loan, accounting_date, esc_tax_bal_p,
rank () over (order by accounting_date desc) AS date_rank
 FROM BALHIST
 where loan = @Loan) BH ON BH.loan=FILMTRAN.loan
JOIN 
(
SELECT loan, cash_date, 
FILMTRAN.transaction079,
CASE FILMTRAN.TRANSACTION079 WHEN 'COLLECTION' THEN TAX_ESCROW
WHEN 'DISBURSEMENT' THEN 0 
END AS TAXESCROWCOLL,
CASE FILMTRAN.TRANSACTION079 WHEN 'DISBURSEMENT' THEN TAX_ESCROW *-1
WHEN 'COLLECTION' THEN 0 
END AS TAXESCROWDIS FROM FILMTRAN
WHERE loan = @Loan)
FT ON FT.loan=FILMTRAN.loan
where FT.cash_date <= FILMTRAN.cash_date 
AND (BH.date_rank ='1' OR BH.accounting_date IS NULL)
AND (len(FT.transaction079) <= len(FILMTRAN.transaction079) OR FT.cash_date < FILMTRAN.cash_date)
GROUP BY FILMTRAN.loan,FILMTRAN.cash_date,  FILMTRAN.transaction079, FILMTRAN.TAX_ESCROW, BH.esc_tax_bal_p) JK ON JK.loan=FILMTRAN.loan AND JK.cash_date = FILMTRAN.cash_date AND JK.transaction079=FILMTRAN.transaction079

WHERE 
FILMTRAN.RVRS_REASON <> 'ERROR_CORR' AND
Loancoll.prim_ind = 'Y' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '1_INQUIRY' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '2_APP_ISS' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '3_APP_ACC' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '4_APPROVED' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '5_COMMITTED' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '9_DELN_SLF' AND
LOANMAST.loan_status <> '9_REJ_BRWR' AND
FILMTRAN.cash_date >= (@FromDate)
AND FILMTRAN.cash_date <= (@ToDate)
AND LOANMAST.loan = @Loan
AND FILMTRAN.tax_escrow <> 0
```

Comment: Does `@FromDate` have a default value set?  Are you certain the user is not entering a date and time?

Comment: @stubaker There is no default value, the user is supposed to enter a time since the FromDate is a parameter within SSRS.

Comment: What is the regional date setting for both the target database and the SSRS database?  Also, are these dates or datetimes?

Comment: @EricHauenstein The regional database settings for both are en-US (LCID-1033).  The SSRS parameter is of datatype date/time since SSRS does not have separate options for date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution to my problem was dumber than I would like to admit. So in addition to stating my solution I will also suggest potential problems/solutions that relate to dates in SSRS/Management Studio:

1. Check the filters on the dataset within SSRS! This was my problem since I used a report template that had filters already on the dataset, even though I usually do all filters by hand in SQL management studio. (See picture below)
2. Make sure the time is correct, not just the date.  For example, 10/1/2013 might appear but the actual value behind that date is something like 10/1/2013 5:43 PM.  So then doing <= will not work if you are trying to include values that happened after 10/1/2013 5:43 PM but before 10/2/2013.
3. Make sure the regional date settings are the same for SSRS and SQL Server. For example, if one machine views dates in the European format of DD/MM/YYYY then it could cause problems if another user's machine is expecting the date to be in MM/DD/YYYY format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a date formatting issue.

Hopefully you are calling a stored procedure to generate your dataset.
If not, you should be!

To see what is happening you might want to output the dates that are getting passed through into a table - then have a look at that table once you have run the report. Obviously you will drop this table once your debugging is complete.
Make sure you store the dates in this table as text rather than DateTime.
Have a look at the diffrences when you run from SSRS and Management Studio.

Comment: I'll look into using a stored procedure to generate the dataset.  Why should  this make a difference?  Also,  The screenshot above is a table showing the two dates after I ran the report.  It is meant to show that even after I run the report, the dates are still technically the same according to SSRS.

Comment: Using a stored procedure gives you two very strong advantages:
1. It's pre-compiled.
2. If you right-click on a table and do a "View Dependencies" you will see your SP in the list - this is helpful for any amendments/upgrades to the table.

If you're building SQL up on the fly to run, then an SP will have few advantages.

If you store the date as a varchar (rather than a date) in your dummy table then hopefully any differences in date will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate this issue. In my system, using SSRS-2008, the results in SSRS are the same as in SQl-Server. I'm using a where clause with an SSRS parameter and a >= operator. I tested with both Text and Date/Time parameter types, and both worked fine.

I would suggest that you make sure that the datasource is the same as what you are querying in SQL server. Also, try entering the date without a time, if you are entering a time in the parameter.

For further assistance, please post your complete query (or a facsimile) and information on your table and parameter settings in SSRS.

EDIT:
Just taking a look at your query here, and I have a feeling that this may be the problem area:

```
where FT.cash_date <= FILMTRAN.cash_date
AND (BH.date_rank ='1' OR BH.accounting_date IS NULL)
AND (len(FT.transaction079) <= len(FILMTRAN.transaction079) OR FT.cash_date < FILMTRAN.cash_date)
```

Possibly could be stemming from confusion over the use of Filmtran without aliasing within the subquery, when it is already included in the main query? I would run the query without the two sub-queries in the From clause and see if the dates are as you'd expect, the add back in the subqueries one by one to determine the location of the issue.

Comment: I edited my original post with more information, I also could not replicate the issue using a much simpler query.  There might be some very specific condition that is occurring in my sql code that is causing the issue?  This is the first time >= has given me any trouble.